# Is diode reverse recovery time related to diode capacitance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, capacitance, signal-theory

The title. Is there some relationship between the two parameters? For example, fast diode recovery time indicates low capacitance, or even farther, can one be calculated from the other? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Charge storage is proportional to area of the junction, as well as other params. Thus capacitance is proportional to the time needed to sweep out the charge.

Comment: I see, so if one were to know capacitance and voltage, would one be able to calculate the time it would take for a certain current to discharge the diode?

Comment: @Jaywalk If it were that simple, then the models wouldn't require a separate parameter. They'd just compute it the way you imagine. Instead, the figure is often generated using time domain reflectometry and under specified conditions and the models use formulas from there to handle variations from the specified conditions. (There is a related parameter used in some models called the saturation delay time constant.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for the response.